# How to blink a text on button in IE ,chrome etc using JQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

To blink a text on button in IE, chrome, safari either using css or JQuery

```
    $('.blink').css('text-decoration','blink');
```

will work in Firefox, not in IE.

Here I want to blink the value of button, not the button entirely.

I am using

```
    <input id="button12" type="button"  class ="button-click" value="X">
```

Here I want to blink button value 'X' only and button will remains unchanged in blink of value i.e button will not blink.

Comment: While I realise that it won't necessarily stop you, and that you, *of course!*, have a really *great* use-case that *absolutely* warrants this feature, there are reasons that it was dropped from CSS...it's really not, under many circumstances, a *good* UI feature. It *really* isn't...

Comment: @DavidThomas: I think main defect of feature is the reducing readable text to users. But I want to give attention to users and blink gives user attention more.

Comment: `<blink>I love the 90's</blink>` :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, here's one that animates:

```
setInterval(blink, 710);
function blink() {
    var elm = $("#button12"),
    mycolor = elm.css('color');
    mycolor == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' ? mycolor='transparent' : mycolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    elm.animate({color: mycolor},300);
}
```

With a [FIDDLE!](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZnGNX/1/)

__

And one that does not animate:

```
setInterval(blink, 500);
function blink() {
    var elm = $("#button12"),
    myval = elm.val();
    myval == "" ? myval="X" : myval="";
    elm.val(myval);
}
```

Also with a [FIDDLE!](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZnGNX/2/)

Answer (score 5):

As the other's said, this usually isn't a good thing to do, but here's an example code for it:

Please note that you have to use a fixed size for the button in order to use this:

```
blink_state = 0;
$(function(){
    window.setInterval(blink,500);
});
function blink(){
    if(blink_state==0){
        $(".blink").text("blinking");
        blink_state=1;
    }
    else{
        $(".blink").text("");
        blink_state=0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vseCx/1/

Comment: @Ineetho: How this will work, [http://jsfiddle.net/vseCx/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/vseCx/2/), Please have a look

Comment: for input buttons, you'll have to do attr("value","X"); instead since the text is in the value attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/vseCx/3/

Answer (score 2):

Really don't know why you'd want to use this but....

```
var timer;
jQuery(function($) {
timer = setTimeout(blnk, 0);
});


function blnk() {
$(".blink").css({opacity: 0}).
    animate({opacity: 1}, 300, "linear").
    animate({opacity: 0}, 300, "linear", 
    function() {
        timer = setTimeout(blnk, 0);
    });
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/TuKax/1/)

And for a button.....

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/TuKax/6/)

Comment: please check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TuKax/2/), here entire button is blinking. How change to only text of that button

Comment: Use a button tag rather than the input tag... http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/TuKax/7/ this ensures that if the user clicks the button, at any time, the value is still passed.

Comment: Is there any idea to keep using input tag, because on keeping button tag  will be very painful to change i.e so many places in js files  want to changed

Comment: Well the problem with altering the value of the input tag is that if a user clicks the input when the value is not visible, then your button has no value and you loose the input. I can't think of a way to do it for an input value. Perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to do it with CSS, but with Javascript it's a yes! take a look at:
[This forum post](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/html-forum/57258-blinking-a-text-in-html.html#post870194)

Comment: @Mahar : Actually there are lot of ways to blink a class, but in my case, I want to blink a button value, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/v3yfr/

```
$("button").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), uset = false, html = $this.html();
    setInterval(function() {
        if ( uset ) {
            $this.html(html);
        } else {
            $this.html("<u>" + html + "</u>");
        }
        uset = !uset;
    }, 150);
});
```

OR: http://jsfiddle.net/v3yfr/2/

```
$("button").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setInterval(function() {
            $this.toggle();
    }, 150);
});
```

FOR INPUT: http://jsfiddle.net/v3yfr/6/

```
$("input[type=submit]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setInterval(function() {
            $this.toggle();
    }, 150);
});
```

OR: http://jsfiddle.net/v3yfr/5/

```
$("input[type=submit]").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), set = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        $this.css({
            "visibility": set ? "hidden" : "visible"
        });
        set = !set;
    }, 150);
});
```

takes care of inline text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using <input id="button12" type="button"  class ="button-click" value="X">  , Here I want to blink 'X' only.

Comment: please check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TuKax/2/). I need the only 'X' to blink, not button background. button will not blink, only value want to blink

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it. Just add an algorithm to generate the appropriate amount of filler spaces and you should be all set.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnGNX/

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnTest" value="My Value" />
```

JavaScript

```
var $myBtn = $("#btnTest");

$myBtn.data("btn", {val: $myBtn.val()}); 
setInterval(function(){
    var defVal = $myBtn.data("btn").val; 
    if($myBtn.val() != defVal){
        $myBtn.val($myBtn.data("btn").val); 
    }else{
        $myBtn.val("             ");
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please bring your answering/working code into the answer itself, that way it's available to other people even when JS Fiddle isn't available (which is quite often, actually).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var currentStyle = 'inline';
         function blinkSpan() {
             if (currentStyle == 'inline') {
                 currentStyle = 'none';
             } else {
                 currentStyle = 'inline';
             }
             document.getElementById('blink').style.display = currentStyle;
             setTimeout('blinkSpan()', 450);
         }
     </script>
```

and in html

```
<button id ="b" >
   Photo<Span id="blink">n </span> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful.

Just use the below java script and use it in your HTML tags with "blink" class.

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function getElementsByClass(searchClass, domNode, tagName) {
        if (domNode == null) domNode = document;
        if (tagName == null) tagName = '*';
        var el = new Array();
        var tags = domNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        var tcl = " " + searchClass + " ";
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            var test = " " + tags[i].className + " ";
            if (test.indexOf(tcl) != -1) el[j++] = tags[i];
        }
        return el;
    }

    function doIt() {
        var elms = getElementsByClass('blink');
        for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++)
            elms[i].style.visibility = (elms[i].style.visibility == "hidden") ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }

    function Knipper() {
        setInterval('doIt()', 400);
    }
    window.onload = Knipper;
</script>
```

and your HTML will be as below.

```html
<span class="blink">Note : </span>
```

(view)source: [www.larshemel.com/forum/blinking_text_in_ie](http://www.larshemel.com/forum/blinking_text_in_ie)